# How to reference js and css files in page head in azure storage?

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-web-roles

How to reference js and css files on page head in azure storage ?

I have tried :

```
CSS/AppConst.css  // --> this working only locally 
~/CSS/AppConst.css
```

I am getting this error :

```
GET http://myapp.azurewebsites.net/CSS/AppConst.css 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Comment: GET http://myapp.azurewebsites.net/CSS/AppConst.css returns `404` but not `500`! `404` means you haven't uploaded the file.

Comment: sorry but "myapp" is not the real name

Comment: And could you provide better code segments from the markup (view/webform) - a full markup, and preferably a `real` name, or at least some meaningless placeholder, because apparently `myapp.azurewebsites.net` is a valid registered Azure Web Site.

Answer (score 0):

In storage, you have to your blob storage as public access

Answer (score 0):

In the webpage you can add these lines of code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">        
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/MyStyle.css"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/MyScript.js"></script>                
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Hi, its not working for me.I put it inside the head and got this error message :Content controls have to be top-level controls in a content page or a nested master page that references a master page.any idea why ?

Comment: You have to create a master page. After create Web Form using a Master Page (linking the master page created previously).